# Facebook send message using HTTP request

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, http, request

I want to send message on facebook. This is my method to make a post request:

```
 public static string http_post(string url, string data)
        {
            var cookiespost = new CookieContainer();
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.CookieContainer = cookiespost;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
            {
                writer.Write(data);
            }

            using (var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                cookies = cookiespost;
                return result;

            }
        }
```

data:

```
"fb_dtsg=AQHcmRlBsZsj&charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2
 C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84&ids%
 5B100002079663653%5D=100002079663653&text_ids%
 5B100002079663653%5D=%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%
 82%D0%B0+%D0%A5%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA&body="
 + textofmessage + "&Send=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%
 D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8";
```

url:

https://m.facebook.com/messages/send/?icm=1

But the message is not sent in the text of the response I get login page.

How is it possible to perform sending a message ?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to authenticate to send a message, look this [link](https://codeoverload.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/posting-to-facebook-with-c/) it might help you

Comment: I authorize before sending the request message , but still get the login page after the request. Thanks for the link.